# Angular view email message

Tags: angular, email

I have an angular application with a spring boot rest service as backend. I have a requirement to display email messages in the UI from the DB. The messages comes in HTML format. I was going to use the angular material modal overlay and write everything on my own to show the message as an overlay. But want to know if there is any npm package/plugin which already does this. I'm going for the look and feel of how the MS Outlook opens an email. Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

To make look and feel similar to Outlook, you can write custom CSS. You can modify REST service data from back end it self having custom classes added. Then add definitions in your custom.css file.

And if you want to display message inside your html template, you can try DomSanitizer. Because of security reasons, Angular wont allow you to render HTML. But using DomSanitizer you can display HTML template.

---

inside .ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export class MyComponent{
    public emailInHTMLFormat :any ; 

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){    }

    getEmailData(){
    
     // Add custom login to get email data from your REST service
     
     this.emailInHTMLFormat = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(YOUR_HTML_DATA); 
    }
}
```

---

inside .html file:

```
<div [innerHtml]="emailInHTMLFormat"> </div>
```